# python range step size not possible using enumerate

Tags: python

Still at the early stages of learning Python. I've written a small piece of code using the range() function:

```
str = "horizon"
# method 2
def printStrInt():
    #print("length of str ",len(str))
    for i in range(0,len(str)-1,2):
        #print("i=",i)
        print("Method 2",myStr[i])

# Calling method
print ("Calling Method")
printStrInt()
```

After this I learnt that there is a new concept called "enumerator", so I tried to rewrite the above as:

```
#method 3
str = "horizon"
def printStrIntervals():
    for count,stringy in enumerate(str):
        print("External to if call count= ",count)
        if (count %2 == 0):
            print("inside if, count= ",count)
            count += 2
            print("inside if + increment, count= ",count)
            print(stringy)

#calling method
print ("Calling Method 3")
printStrIntervals()
```

The trouble is with method 3. The "count += 2" call does increment the variable "count" by two, but when the "for" loop iterates, count hasn't actually jumped up by two. Can you please advise what is the right way to make enumerate work the same as Range?

Comment: Something you should perhaps note is that `str` is a reserved word for the built-in type of strings. I would name it `string` or `s` instead.

Comment: What is the expected output?  What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: Nothing you do to the variable(s) of a `for` loop will have any effect beyond the current iteration - they will be always be assigned new value(s) from the iterator being looped over.  `enumerate()` has no equivalent to `range()`'s step parameter - perhaps you could use `enumerate(s[::2])`?

Comment: It *does* increment it by two, but on the next iteration, it is assigned the value from the iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're violating the use model of `enumerate`: it is for smooth iteration over a data object, not for jumping items.  It's an extension of `for stringy in my_str`, not `for count in range(len(my_str))`.

Also, *any* time you alter the loop index within the loop, you're violating the `for` assumptions, and you are at the mercy of language semantics.  You tried to alter those semantics, and escaped with a mere "you can't do that", rather than a crash.

If you want to make an intermittent skip, then simply build your own `while`.  This is the proper use: `for` is applicable when you know how many times you will execute the loop *at the time of loop entry*.

```
count = 0

while count < len(my_str):
    stringy = my_str[count]
    ...
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not considered good practice to modify the `for`-loop variables (here: `count` and `stringy`). Consider using the code below instead:

```
str = "horizon"
def printStrIntervals_mod():
    for count,stringy in enumerate(str):
        print("External to if call count= ",count)
        if (count %2 == 0):
            print("inside if, count= ",count)
            print(stringy)

#calling function
print("Calling Method 3")
printStrIntervals_mod()
```

Comment: You can modify the looping variables all you want you just have to understand what that means and how on each iteration they will be assigned new values